# Antiquated uses of haber

Tags: selección-de-palabras, verbos, rae, haber

Today, someone told me that `haber` can be used to indicate possession, apparently because in early Spanish `haber` was used to mean `tener`. They gave the specific example of:

```
Hemos un bocadillo (We have a sandwich)
```

Is this a valid construct? I was told that although 90% of `haber`'s uses are as an auxiliary verb, its function as a verb to indicate a possessive is not entirely gone, and that erudite individuals can use `haber` in this way to sound intelligent or archaic, in a similar way to how contemporary English speakers use `thou`.

Also - In Spanish, the phrase 'haber de' can be used to indicate an obligation in a way that is similar to the construct 'tener que'. For example:

```
He de trabajar mañana (I have to work tomorrow)
```

The same individual also told that this is rare, archaic way of forming the future tense and that the endings for future tense verbs come from the endings of `haber`'s present tense conjugations.

```
He de ir a la playa.
Iré a la playa.
```

Are these two statements above really equivalent? Were they at any point in time?

Comment: Note that the etimology of the future tense in Spanish is a composite of `haber`. `Trabajaré mañana` evolved from `Trabajar he mañana`, `Iré a la playa` from `Ir he a la playa` and so on.

Answer (score 4):

Using *haber* to express possession could certainly be used back in the day (where it had the imperative forms *habe* and *habed*), but it developed today into the virtually exclusively auxiliary (for perfects) and impersonal (for existential statements) verb we have today.  There are a few situations where you might use it in legal or other contexts where language has been stuck in formulaic constructions (such as *habida cuenta de* - *teniendo en cuenta el hecho de*), but that's really about it.

*haber de [inf.]* can be used to indicate obligation.  It's considered equivalent to *tener que* as you mention, just that *tener que* is more common.

*Haber de [inf.]* for future is still seen in modern Spanish, though certainly no where near as common as simple future or the other periphrastic future of *ir a [inf.]*.  This usage is no where near as common as *haber de* for obligation, but you can absolutely use it as a way to indicate the future.<sup>1</sup>

*Haber* is actually where the future tense came from in Spanish, a combination of an infinitive and the verb haber.  So you'd have *nadar he* or *comer has* which eventually were reduced to *nadaré* and *comerás* (for a time, you could even find the pronouns in between, as in *dar me has* -> *darmeás* -> *me darás<sub>/darasme</sub>*.

Note that there are *other* older uses that you'll see once in a while.  One of them is for denoting time, instead of using *hacer*.  So instead of *hace cinco años que...*, you can say *cinco años ha que...*.  There's also the construction *haberselas* that allows the archaic conjugation of habermos: *Nos las habemos con esa gentuza*.

---

<sup>1. However, they are not exactly equivalent.  Not that *iré* is true future, whereas *he de ir*, in its future interpretation, is still technically present tense.  In simple statements, this makes no difference, but can affect tense ordering in subordinate clauses.</sup>

Answer (score 4):

> in early Spanish "haber" was used to mean "tener"

That's right, and the evolution can be followed from the English analog:

> **Yo he un caballo   = I have a horse**  (old Spanish)
>
> **Yo he un caballo comprado  = I have a bought horse**  (here *'comprado/bought'*
> is an *adjetive*)
>
> **Yo he comprado un caballo  = I have bought a horse**  (this was
> originally the same as above, but "comprado" evolved from
> adjective to verb, in participle)

The only difference is that in English "have" retained the old meaning, as a plain verb (to posess) and it also gained the new meaning (auxiliary verb). While in Spanish the old use almost disappeared.

This is explained (in Spanish) [here](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?haber).

Today the old meaning ("haber" = "tener") is rare.

See also the [dictionary](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=5ra5cGATFDXX2hZam4lB)

> Also - In Spanish, the phrase 'haber de' can be used to indicate an obligation in a way that is similar to the construct 'tener que'.

Yes, that's also right. It's a rather convoluted way of express some obligation, or purpose, or expectation - or simply: future.

> **He de** trabajar mañana (I have to work tomorrow)

Not extremely rare, but kind of special. Some examples:

> **Has de** saber que... (*You should/must know/learn  that...*)
>
> No **he de** descansar hasta haber entendido... (*I won't rest until having understood...*)
>
> Es la realidad, y **hemos de** aceptarla (*That's reality, and we must accept it*)

Regarding

> *He de ir a la playa.*
>
> *Iré a la playa.*
>
> Are these two statements above really equivalent? Were they at any point in time?

At least in current usage, the second is the normal one, the first is a "stylized" way of saying the same, it could be used to emphasize obligation, or determination.

Comment: I disagree with your last statement. `He de ir a la playa` gives the idea of some sort of duty or obligation. On the other hand, `iré a la playa` is just plain future tense.